# reading from serial from linux command line

Tags: linux, serial-port

I have a serial port device that I would like to test using linux command line.

I am able to use stty and echo for sending commands to serial port, but when device responds I have no way of reading what is coming from serial port. I am using

`stty -F /dev/ttyS0 speed 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb &&
echo -n ^R^B > /dev/ttyS0`

to send a command to the device. Device operates and sends a response back in 300 ms's. How do I print that response to the console using command line?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Same as with output.  Example:

```
cat /dev/ttyS0
```

Or:

```
cat < /dev/ttyS0
```

The first example is an app that opens the serial port and relays what it reads from it to its `stdout` (your console).  The second is the shell directing the serial port traffic to any app that you like; this particular app then just relays its `stdin` to its `stdout`.

To get better visibility into the traffic, you may prefer a hex dump:

```
od -x < /dev/ttyS0
```

Comment: or `socat stdio /dev/ttyS0`

Comment: I sent a command to a device I am working with.  The command is : echo "1GAINS" | sudo tee /dev/ttyUSB0 .... and in response I am getting an infinite stream repeating the same message.  Any ideas?  The device itself should echo back the command I send once, but here it's like I'm getting weird feedback.

Comment: I verified that the feedback is not "real" using a serial analyzer.  The device only echos the command back once, but using the above commands I get a crazy endless repetition on the terminal output.

Comment: Does it work with binary data ?

Comment: @ransh - See the hex dump part of the answer.  You'll ultimately need a human or a tool who understands or who can reverse engineer that particular binary data.

Comment: `cat` rarely works, in my experience; it just returns with nothing. but `screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200` works pretty reliably

Answer (score 24):

I am monitoring output for arduino uno like:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
```

Comment: This worked best for me to see all the data being written to the USB tty port.  `cat` would immediately exit where screen runs continuously until killed via CTRL-A k command.

Comment: Exit: Ctrl-A, k, y

Comment: This worked on Raspberry Pi as well after installing screen